# Getting "Server response: 409" while jf gp

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am facing the following error while trying to publish Go module to local Go registry on JFROG.

The command I used is:

```
jf gp --project <project_name> v0.0.0-20210107165309-348f09dbbbc0
```

I also faced a similar error while publishing with CURL:

```
curl -X PUT -H  "X-JFrog-Art-Api:TOKEN" -H "X-Explode-Archive: true" <ARTIFACTORY_URL> -T github.com.zip
```

The error response was:

> "message" : "Error during deployment: Cannot deploy file 'v0.0.0-20170929234023-d6e3b3328b78.mod'. The repository 'repo' rejected the resolution of an artifact 'repo:github.com/!azure/go-ansiterm/@v/v0.0.0-20170929234023-d6e3b3328b78.mod' due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy."

Though while trying with clean versions like v0.4.0 both `jf gp` and `curl` work fine.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some property that need to be configured at JFROG end to enable snapshot version handling. Unfortunately I do not have privileges to manage the go registry configuration. Hope the attached snapshot helps.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error "*due to conflict in the snapshot release handling policy*" usually means that the request is rejected by the repository as there is a conflict with actual repository behaviour to handle snapshots and releases.

Hence, enable the "Handle Releases" and "Handle Snapshots" checkboxes under the concerned Artifactory's repository configuration settings. This should help to resolve the issue. Refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-LocalandRemoteRepositories) page more details on these settings.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but this applies for maven type repo as per my understanding. I am looking for go type repository.

Comment: Can you please validate if maven type is selected for repository. Also, share complete log for this action from Artifactory side.